# Rotated an model in Unity?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am Bulid an project where when If :

1. user swipe left the model model should be rotated left.
2. user swipe right the model model should be rotated rifgt.
3. user swipe down the model model should be rotated down.
4. user swipe up the model model should be rotated up.

What I did till Now is :

Add an 3D model in front of the camera. made C# file.

Now What I need is that some basic code From that I can make it rotated on swipe. How To run This project In my phone.

Here is the basic code that come after I build my first C# file of that model :

```
void Start()

}
void Update(){}
}
```

Comment: I looked at some of your other questions as this seemed to be a joke. The other questions seem better written and you clearly have a larger understanding than what is suggested in this question and your comments on the answer from Ludovic. Whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Rotate` to achieve the rotation of your model (see [Rotate documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html))

Then use [this example](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/600148/detect-swipe-in-four-directions-android.html)  to detect swipe in each direction.

You can try something like this:

```
var speed = 0.1;
function Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

        // Get movement of the finger since last frame
        var touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

        // Move object across XY plane
        var rotationVector = new Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x, touchDeltaPosition.y, 0);
        transform.Rotate(rotationVector * speed, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks can you please giud me little more as I am new to it.. I had make C# file and close it Now when I am click that file but it is not opening. How can I open the file and use your documentation code

Comment: @Neal what do you mean by opening the file?

Comment: @Neal Do you know how to code in C#? it's maybe a little bit soon to try Unity if you don't know how to code.

Comment: I know how to code can you please help me in telling how to open the file of C# from assest please

Comment: As when I am click it an other software is loading but after 2 sec. it close and my file is not open

Comment: @Neal i don't know what is your problem, i edited my answer see if it's works

Comment: My problem is that I had made an file c# that is showing in assest but when I am clicking it. This file used to open in other page but now It is not opening. Hope You had understand It if not please tell me..

Comment: Hey, I had added your code and run it still nothing is happening can you please If i want to add some extar property or anything